# Python animation of two sublot

Tags: python, subplot

I'm trying to have an animation of two or more subplots. Actually this is the code of the subplots, I would like to have a loop animation of these two sublots.

```
k=5
mutual=dict((x,hf.II(data, set(['(t-'+str(k-x-i)+')' for i in range(0,k)]),set(['(t)']))) for x in range (0,k))
names = range(len(list(mutual.keys())))
values = list(mutual.values())

k=5
z=10
mutual2=dict((x,hf.II(data, set(['(t-'+str(z-x-i)+')' for i in range(0,k)]),set(['(t)']))) for x in range (0,k))
names2 = range(len(list(mutual2.keys())))
values2 = list(mutual2.values())

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(7, 4), sharey=True)
axs[0, 0].bar(names, values)
axs[0, 1].scatter(names, values)
axs[1, 0].bar(names2, values2)
axs[1, 1].scatter(names2, values2)
fig.suptitle('Cumulative Info of   previous instants')
```

with this result

[image]

But I would like to have this:

[image]